# std::map::insert with C++17 calling copy constructor of pair with non copyable types

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, c++17, rvalue

I get an error saying that the compiler is trying to use `std::pair<const K, V>`'s copy constructor with `std::map` in the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Something {
public:
    Something(const Something&) = delete;
    Something(Something&&) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
    Something() = default;
};

int main() {
    auto map = std::map<int, Something>{};
    map.insert({1, Something{}});
}
```

The error is here https://wandbox.org/permlink/OeyxtMjLy6HvJI5L (reproduced below)

```
note: 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const int; _T2 = Something]' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
       constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
                 ^~~~
```

This is strange because the new C++17 rules changed the overloads of insert to accept `const value_type&` and `value_type&&` as opposed to the previous template forwarding reference version of `insert` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert).  Which prohibited use of list initialization among other things (curious why they didn't provide a default template parameter to the other `insert` overload which would have had similar behavior but that is another question)

The rvalue version of the `value_type` should be selected.  Then why is the pair copy constructor being selected?  Does this comment in the libstdc++ code have to do with anything https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_map.h#L805?

This error does not appear on clang (https://wandbox.org/permlink/oBoe871dmfo1AP37)  Not sure if this is a standard library issue on wandbox or a compiler problem.  If this is a compiler issue then who is right?

Comment: Not really an answer, but this does seem like a case C++17's `try_emplace` was designed for, and actually looks cleaner with: `map.try_emplace(1)` (`Something`'s constructor takes no arguments, so you don't have to pass anything for it).

Comment: @ShadowRanger yeah I am using a workaround right now with `map.insert(std::make_pair(...))`

Comment: GCC added that overload in [October 2017](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/32973e22775a88be8045ae89accb09f4e642c29a#diff-2433c146f778f8cd2b79089d72fc2a91), well after the release date of GCC 7. Nothing to see here.

Comment: @T.C. want to make that an answer?